# How to flush out suspended WCF workflows from the instancestore?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

We have identified the need to flush out several different workflows that have been suspended/persisted for a long time (i.e. hung instances). This is so that our test environment can be flushed clean before acceptance tests are re-run.

The dirty solution is to use a sql script to remove records from the InstancesTable and other related tables in the database.

What's the proper solution?

These are WCF workflows.

Test rig is running XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it (thanks to Pablo Rotondo on MSDN):

http://www.funkymule.com/post/2010/04/28/how-to-resume-suspended-workflows-in-net-40.aspx

Comment: Though Maurice's suggestion is far better if you are not stuck with XP!

Answer (score 2):

Using the AppFabric you can use the UI, or I asume PowerShell commands, to delete individual instanced. For development and test purposes I normally just recreate the database by running SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql script again.

Comment: I don't believe you can use AppFabric on XP? The test team has rejected doing anything directly to the databse.